# Is there a term for a phrase in which an antonym can be switched-in and yet it still retains the same, or synonymous, meaning as the original?

Tags: synonyms, antonyms, auto-antonyms

For example,

Based on/Based off,
Break up/Break down,
Write up/Write down,
Up for/Down for,
Went on/Went off,
Slow up/Slow down

These all retain similar meanings when substituting with antonyms.

This would be the opposite to switching-in an antonym to contrast the distinct meanings of an auto-antonym.
For example,

Bolt on/Bolt off,
Clip on/Clip off,
Dust on/Dust off